# Code ran until I closed the file and reopened it, now NIntegration gets stopped by a nonnumerical value

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I ran this code earlier, and even saved a pdf of the plot. After closing the file and reopening it later in the day, I came to find that it will not run anymore (I truly think that I saved it before closing, but oh well). Here is the code

```
rCMid[x_, y_, z_,ϕ1_, z1_] := {x - R*Cos[ϕ1], 
  y - R*Sin[ϕ1], z - z1}
rCNormMid[x_, y_, z_,ϕ1_, z1_] := 
 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + z1^2 + R^2 - 2*z*z1 - 
   2*R*(x*Cos[ϕ1] + y*Sin[ϕ1])]

rCTop[x_, y_, z_, 
  r1_, ϕ1_] := {x - r1*Cos[ϕ1], y - 
    r1*Sin[ϕ1], z - L/2}
rCNormTop[x_, y_, z_, r1_, ϕ1_] := 
 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + (L/2)^2 + r1^2 - z*L - 
   2*r1*(x*Cos[ϕ1] + y*Sin[ϕ1])]

rCBottom[x_, y_, z_, 
  r1_,ϕ1_] := {x - r1*Cos[ϕ1], y - 
    r1*Sin[ϕ1], z + L/2}
rCNormBottom[x_, y_, z_, r1_,ϕ1_] := 
 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + (L/2)^2 + r1^2 + z*L - 
   2*r1*(x*Cos[ϕ1] + y*Sin[ϕ1])]

eleCyl[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ, 
  R_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(rCMid[x, y, z,ϕ1, z1]/
      rCNormMid[x, y, z,ϕ1, z1]^3)*R, {ϕ1, 0, 
    2*\[Pi]}, {z1, -L/2, L/2}, AccuracyGoal -> 8] + 
  NIntegrate[(rCTop[x, y, z, r1,ϕ1]/
      rCNormTop[x, y, z, r1,ϕ1]^3)*r1, {ϕ1, 0, 
    2*\[Pi]}, {r1, 0, R}, AccuracyGoal -> 8] + 
  NIntegrate[(rCBottom[x, y, z, r1,ϕ1]/
      rCNormBottom[x, y, z, r1,ϕ1]^3)*r1, {ϕ1, 0, 
    2*\[Pi]}, {r1, 0, R}, AccuracyGoal -> 8]

vecPlotCyl = 
  With[{R = 0.5, L = 3}, 
   VectorPlot3D[
    eleCyl[x, y, z, L, R], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -4, 4}, 
    VectorStyle -> {"Arrow3D", Medium}, 
    VectorColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", VectorPoints -> 8]];
```

Here is the error it gives me when i try to run the Vector3DPlot:

NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (0.5 (-3.99886-z1))/(33.9806 +<<5>>)^(3/2) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,6.28319},{-(3/2),3/2}}.

Which leads me to believe it is an issue with my function rCMid, but I just can not figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NIntegrate does not recognize R and L in the integrand. Define it explicitly in your functions:

```
rCMid[x_, y_, z_, \[Phi]1_, z1_, R_] = {x - R*Cos[\[Phi]1], 
y - R*Sin[\[Phi]1], z - z1}
rCNormMid[x_, y_, z_, \[Phi]1_, z1_, R_] = 
Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + z1^2 + R^2 - 2*z*z1 - 
2*R*(x*Cos[\[Phi]1] + y*Sin[\[Phi]1])]

rCTop[x_, y_, z_, r1_, \[Phi]1_, L_] = {x - r1*Cos[\[Phi]1], 
y - r1*Sin[\[Phi]1], z - L/2}
rCNormTop[x_, y_, z_, r1_, \[Phi]1_, L_] = 
Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + (L/2)^2 + r1^2 - z*L - 
2*r1*(x*Cos[\[Phi]1] + y*Sin[\[Phi]1])]

rCBottom[x_, y_, z_, r1_, \[Phi]1_, L_] = {x - r1*Cos[\[Phi]1], 
y - r1*Sin[\[Phi]1], z + L/2}
rCNormBottom[x_, y_, z_, r1_, \[Phi]1_, L_] = 
Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + (L/2)^2 + r1^2 + z*L - 
2*r1*(x*Cos[\[Phi]1] + y*Sin[\[Phi]1])]

eleCyl[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ, 
R_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[(rCMid[x, y, z, \[Phi]1, z1, R]/
  rCNormMid[x, y, z, \[Phi]1, z1, R]^3)*R, {\[Phi]1, 0, 
2*\[Pi]}, {z1, -L/2, L/2}, AccuracyGoal -> 8] +
NIntegrate[(rCTop[x, y, z, r1, \[Phi]1, L]/
  rCNormTop[x, y, z, r1, \[Phi]1, L]^3)*r1, {\[Phi]1, 0, 
2*\[Pi]}, {r1, 0, R}, AccuracyGoal -> 8] +
NIntegrate[(rCBottom[x, y, z, r1, \[Phi]1, L]/
  rCNormBottom[x, y, z, r1, \[Phi]1, L]^3)*r1, {\[Phi]1, 0, 
2*\[Pi]}, {r1, 0, R}, AccuracyGoal -> 8]

vecPlotCyl = 
With[{R = 0.5, L = 3}, 
VectorPlot3D[
eleCyl[x, y, z, L, R], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -4, 4}, 
VectorStyle -> {"Arrow3D"}, VectorColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
VectorPoints -> 8]]
```

[image]